# Mootools: same function generates error when used on individual elements?

Tags: function, mootools

this is the error i get:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method`

this is the code in the domready function:

```
    $$('.accordion_content').slide('hide');
    $$('.accordion_header').addEvent('click', function(e) {
        this.getParent().getElement('.accordion_content').slide('toggle');
        this.toggleClass('header_highlight');
    });
        //  set horizontal slide for sidebar
    $('priceNPay').slide('hide', 'horizontal');
    $('theSidebar').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        //  THIS IS WHERE IT ERRORS OUT... WHY!?
    $('theSidebar').addevent('click', function(e) {
        this.getElement('priceNPay').slide('toggle');
        this.toggleClass('header_highlight');
    });
```

the first chunk of code works fine.  toggles like mad on all `<div>` elements with the relevant class.  the second chunk of code hides the `<div>`, changes the `<div>`'s colour...but errors out when trying to do the `addEvent`.

WHYYYY!!!????

the structure of the the only difference i can think would be relevant...if it didn't work:

```
<div id='someName'>
  <h1>title text</h1>
  <div id='someOtherName'>  (on the sidebar, this is an 'article' element)
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i'm not following is why it'll hide, but then won't target for the toggle...?

thanks gang.

WR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `addevent` instead of `addEvent`.

Comment: FMS.  i need to be clubbed like a baby seal.  that's just frickin' wrong.  :(  i go to do penance in a slaughterhouse...  **shame**  WR!